# How to fix Typelib generated by MIDL?

Tags: python, midl, comtypes

I am trying to generate typelib of INetCfg interface using IDL [in this page](http://www.mail-archive.com/comtypes-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00016.html), seen below:

```
import "netcfgx.idl";

[
        uuid(d99085ff-c5d7-4a4c-a987-91a513e268a9),
        version(1.0),
        helpstring("NetCfgX 1.0 Type Library")
]
library NetCFGLib
{
        interface IEnumNetCfgBindingInterface;
        interface IEnumNetCfgBindingPath;
        interface IEnumNetCfgComponent;
        interface INetCfg;
        interface INetCfgProperties;
        interface INetCfgLock;
        interface INetCfgBindingInterface;
        interface INetCfgBindingPath;
        interface INetCfgComponentBindings;
        interface INetCfgBindingPath;
        interface INetCfgClass;
        interface INetCfgComponent;
        interface INetCfgIdentification;
        interface INetCfgClassSetup;
};
```

Unfortunately, the generated IDL still can't be loaded from comtype, with code given below:

```
        import comtypes.client as cc
        cc.GetModule("C:\path\to\netcfg.tlb")
```

It gives this error `WindowsError: [Error -2147312566] Error loading type library/DLL`

How do I fix this error?
I am using Windows 7 64 bit, and Python 27 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I use Windows 7 64bit, just solved this issue, by first running WDK `setenv.bat <path_to_wdk> x64`. After that, generate the typelib either using `midl netcfg.idl /env x64` (for 64bit TLB) or `midl netcfg.idl` (for 32bit TLB).

I opted to use generate the 64bit TLB

Hope it helps somebody who just get in touch with this COM beast!